# I am new to java and can not figure out why my code does not print out both the text file and the letter occurrence

Tags: java

My code prints only the first line of the file and the linecount is 1. 
However the array prints the correct amount of the letters. How can I change 
my code to print both text and letter occurrence. Also i want to print in the 
27th position of the array non alphabetic character such as symbol and 
spaces.Thanks in advance.

```
 import java.io.*;
 public class Test { 
 public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {

     int lineCount=0; // Variale used to count the numbers of line. 
     int nextChar;
     char c;

     File file = new File("file.txt");  //  file in same folder

     BufferedReader readFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); 
     String lines= " "; 
     int[] count = new int[27];
     char ch;

     while ((lines = readFile.readLine()) != null){

        System.out.println(lines);
        while ((nextChar = readFile.read()) != -1) {
        ch = ((char) nextChar);

            // Does this code count even uppercase or shall i  
            // convert it the text to lower case.

            if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
                count[ch - 'a']++;

            }
        }
        lineCount++;
    }

    System.out.println("file.txt containes " + lineCount + " lines.");

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%c %d", i + 'A', count[i]);
    }        
} 
}
```

Comment: In your inner while loop, its reading all the chars like '\n' etc,.. so the outer loop executes only once as inner loop reaches EOF, so linecount is 1.

Comment: I think what you want is to read from lines variable instead of reader in inner loop because the condition will read to eof and readline will only read once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close with your original answer!

The main problem was the nested `while` loop which was reading to the end of the file - that's why the first line was printed and the counts were correct but the other lines were not printed.
The reason for that is `BufferedReader` is backed by a buffer (as the name suggests). The first call to `readLine` returned a `String` containing all the characters in the buffer up to the first newline character. Each call to the `read` method in the following while loop then moved the position of the buffer along by one character until it reached the end of the file, at which point the `read` method returns -1 and the loop is exited. By the time the second call to `readLine` is made the buffer is already at the end position so a `null` is returned.

You can solve the problem by iterating over the bytes within the line returned from the call to the readLine method.

Here's a working example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int lineCount = 0;// Variale used to count the numbers of line.
    File file = new File("file.txt");  //  file in same folder

    BufferedReader readFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String lines;
    int[] count = new int[27];
    char ch;

    while ((lines = readFile.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(lines);
        for (byte charByte : lines.getBytes()) {
            ch = (char) charByte;

            // Does this code count even uppercase or shall i convert
            // it the text to lower case.

            if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
                count[ch - 'a']++;
            // Count non-alpha characters here. Node: this will count numeric values also...
            } else if (ch < 'A' || ch > 'Z') {
                count[26]++;
            }
        }
        lineCount++;
    }

    System.out.println("file.txt containes " + lineCount + " lines.");

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%c: %d\n", i + 'A', count[i]);
    }
    System.out.printf("Special characters: %d\n", count[26]);
}
```

Comment: How to read lower and upper case as equivalent. For example "a" and "A" will rise the count to 2. I tried to convert all the file to lower case but couldn't.

Comment: You can convert the line in your while look to lower case. So just before you print the line, you could do: line = line.toLowerCase(); Strings are immutable so you need to assign it back to either its self or a new String variable.

Answer (score 1):

Every letter is mapped differently in the ASCII standard. Taking alphabetic characters you have:

- `A - Z` is mapped on `65-90` decimal.
- `a - z` is mapped on `97-122` decimal.

So to solve you problem you can simply read the letters in ignore-case mode, either all lowercase or all uppercase.

PS: [Here](http://www.asciitable.com/) you have a full ASCII table for further reference.

Comment: Java's text datatypes don't use ASCII. But you knew that already, right? (`String wink = ""`). See [Class Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html).

Comment: @TomBlodget Let's say that it all began with ASCII. For the sake of the example I took it, because I believe that the answer still applies and in this variation is simpler to discuss. But yeah, you did well to specify the detail.